# jQuery/ JavaScript not working in IE 8 only

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

```
// Use a black icon for secondary (grey gradient) backgrounds.

if ($(this).hasClass('secondary') || $(this).css('color') === 'rgb(0, 0, 0)') {
    filename = 'newwin-black-white-15-14.png';
}
```

The above code is not working in IE8

Comment: which version of jQuery? 1.12 above has dropped support to ie8 and less.

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors reported?

Comment: jQuery 2.0 and no errors reported, while debugging it skips the if condition only in IE8

Answer (score 0):

Internet explorer 8 wont return rgb values for color, you should do as follows in order to cover all cases:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('secondary') || $(this).css('color') === 'rgb(0, 0, 0)' || $(this).css('color') === '#000'  || $(this).css('color') === '#000000') {
    filename = 'newwin-black-white-15-14.png';
}
```